# Unicode Characters aren't working on urxvt terminal

Tags: icons, unicode, rxvt, vifm

I want to change my terminal from gnome to urxvt. But there are some issues in urxvt that I cannot resolve. I use vifm for my terminal file manager. Vifm looks different when I am in urxvt.

This is what it looks like when I am in gnome-terminal.
[image: gnome-terminal]

And this is what it looks like when I am in urxvt.
[image: urxvt]

Clearly the file icons aren't working in urxvt. Someone suggested me to use another font, it isn't solving the problem. I have used source code pro font at first.

This is the font I am using.

```
URxvt.font:               xft:monospace:size=10
```

Comment: You might want to see https://github.com/cirala/vifm_devicons as it states that you need NERDfont set as your default font for the folder icons, etc to show up properly.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.